# I want to exclude companies that have 0 from the chart

Tags: excel, graph

[image: Bar graph & data example]

I want my bar graph not to display names with 0. So I want it to only show names with actual values!

I know how to suppress 0 or make it as gap on the chart but I want to delete the names with 0 value so that it does not show on the graph.

Comment: It's hard to give specific advice without knowing your data. I would recommend either deleting the companies from the original dataset or even better creating a separate dataset without the 0 companies and using that as a datasource.

Comment: @M.Schalk Sorry, I added the snap of the current situation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make a pivot table of your original data table and add a filter for the rows that you don't want displayed.

You can then make a pivot chart from this pivot table which will dynamically show data not included in your pivot table.

[image]

[image]